Intel Vtune throwing Sampling Driver Error
I've been trying to use intel v tune to record performance characteristics of a cxl simulator, but every time i try to access the micro-architecture characteristics or any other parameters, it says i need to have a sampling driver installed. I already do have a sampling driver installed but for some reason the same error keeps popping up no matter what I do. Are there any suggestions for what I should do next to solve this issue?
I've tried to find the file path to where the sampling driver is and change the command line respectively but that tosses up another error and won't run at all.
